# return string; not working without curly brackets

Tags: c++, xml, string, curly-brackets

This is the function I have in a .h file:

```
static std::string ReturnString(std::string some_string)
    return ("\t<" + some_string + " ");
```

The compiler (g++ -std=c++0x -pedantic -Wall -Wextra) throws these errors:

```
error:expected identifier before '(' token
error:named return values are no longer supported
error:expected '{' at end of input
warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
```

But,

```
static std::string ReturnString(std::string some_string)
{
    return ("\t<" + some_string + " ");
}
```

works fine.
Even,

```
static std::string ReturnString(std::string some_string)
{
    return "\t<" + some_string + " ";
}
```

works too.

Could someone please explain this to me please? Am I missing some basic knowledge of strings?

Thanks.

Comment: Just basic knowledge of functions : you always have to enclose a function's body between curly braces, even when it's only one line long. And that's about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static std::string ReturnString(std::string some_string)
    return ("\t<" + some_string + " ");
```

It's actually a basic knowledge of C++ that you're missing.  In C++, function bodies must be enclosed in curly braces, `{}`.  So, the correct definition for the function above would be:

```
static std::string ReturnString(std::string some_string)
{
    return ("\t<" + some_string + " ");
}
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks. Embarrassed. Have done one line functions before in the same line with {} and just an enter into second line made me forget the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with strings. This is about how you have defined your function. In this case, `ReturnString` is a function which returns a string.

General format for C++ function definition is:

```
ReturnType NameOfTheFunction(Parameters)
{
    Implementation
}
```

Comment: Or `auto NameOfTheFunction(Parameters) -> ReturnType { Implementation }`.

Comment: or soon `auto Name(Parameter) { return /* something */; };` :)

Comment: The last semicolon is not required right? But is that the standard practice?